# When do I need the keyword noConflict in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I've seen a few methods of using `jQuery.noConflict`. But it seems that it's not always necessary.

```js
// define $
var $ = function() {
    alert("Hello World");
};

// use $ where it's not jQuery
$();

// 1
// jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('body').append("<p>foo</p>");
});

// 2
// jQuery.noConflict();
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $('body').append("<p>foo</p>");
    });
})(jQuery);

// 3
// $.noConflict() here to tell jQuery to ignore $, but we're using *jQuery* when ready
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('body').append("<p>foo</p>");
});

// use $ where it's not jQuery
$();
```

The only need of `jQuery.noConflict` is when we define an alias of jQuery

```js
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
j(document).ready(function() {
    j('body').append("<p>foo</p>");
});
```

So in what situation (besides creating an alias) that the `jQuery.noConflict()` can not be ommitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have single version of jQuery and no framework is used which can conflict with each other you can omit [jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/),

> Some other popular JavaScript frameworks are: MooTools, Backbone,
>   Sammy, Cappuccino, Knockout, JavaScript MVC, Google Web Toolkit,
>   Google Closure, Ember, Batman, and Ext JS.
>
> Some of the other frameworks also use the $ character as a shortcut
>   (just like jQuery), and then you suddenly have two different
>   frameworks using the same shortcut, which might result in that your
>   scripts stop working.
>
> The jQuery team have already thought about this, and implemented the
>   noConflict() method. [Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_noconflict.asp)

In JQuery documents.

> Many JavaScript libraries use $ as a function or variable name, just
>   as jQuery does. In jQuery's case, $ is just an alias for jQuery, so
>   all functionality is available without using $. If you need to use
>   another JavaScript library alongside jQuery, return control of $ back
>   to the other library with a call to $.noConflict(). Old references of
>   $ are saved during jQuery initialization; noConflict() simply restores
>   them. [Reference](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Answer (score 1):

Many JavaScript libraries use $ as a function or variable name, just as jQuery does. In jQuery's case, $ is just an alias for jQuery, so all functionality is available without using $.

If you need to use another JavaScript library alongside jQuery, return control of $ back to the other library with a call to $.noConflict(). Old references of $ are saved during jQuery initialization; noConflict() simply restores them.